# Quarkus asynchronous and paralell requests with vert.x

Tags: asynchronous, vert.x, quarkus

I have a Quarkus App that reads a file and sends requests (to another Quarkus microservice). At the moment, I send one request for each line of the file. But the process takes so long because I have thousand of lines.

I've read about vert.x and I've got an asynchronous request to the API, thanks to this link:

https://quarkus.io/blog/mutiny-concurrent-uni/

**But** my problem is that I have to save the response of the requests to an Array and at the end, save the file. So the problem is that the process finishes and the result of the file is empty (because the request are async and they are invoking in that moment)

This is my code to make async requests:

```
 this.client = WebClient.create(vertx,
              new WebClientOptions().setSsl(true).setTrustAll(true));
            
 client.postAbs("http://localhost:8082/myApi")
      .sendJson(myDto)
      .subscribe().with(a->this.processRecord(a.bodyAsString());
```

I know that I have to wait until the async process with the ArrayList with all records is finished and then, when everything is complete save the file. And I've read about CompletableFuture and I think it may works but I don't know **where I have to wait and how**.

PS: Probably there could be another way to do that. I'd like to know anyway.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `subscribe`, use `await().atMost(Duration.ofSeconds(...))`, or `await().indefinitely()` (not recommended as it may block forever). Both will return the `HTTPResponse`.

Now, without much context, it's hard to understand how your method is used. In general, we don't use `await()`, because the call is also asynchronous and so expect to receive a `Uni`.

Comment: Hi @Clement, thank you very much for your answer (and also for your article!). Basically if I have to handle 500K requests, I don't want to do it one by one because the process can take too long. So I think the best way to do it is with a parallel or asynchronous request, right? Also, I don't need to wait any seconds until the response is received. I only want to do all requests in paralell and once they are completed, do "things". Thanks.

Comment: So, what you need is "combine":
```
Uni<Map<String, Response>> uni = Uni.combine()
        .all().unis(uniA, uniB, ....).combinedWith( // Enqueue your 500K requests or use a list
                listOfResponses -> {
                    Map<String, Response> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
                    map.put("A", (Response) listOfResponses.get(0));
                    map.put("B", (Response) listOfResponses.get(1));
                    return map;
                }
        );
```

See: https://smallrye.io/smallrye-mutiny/guides/combining-items

Comment: Thank you. But what can I do then with "Uni<Map<String, Response>>" object?Do I have to subscribe to anything? With this way it doesn't print anything:
uniCombine.subscribe().with(a->System.out.println(a.get("A")));

Comment: This is the code:
https://gist.github.com/lferna/24db1dd494b0542e4e0bea71fdaed8e5

Comment: Yes, to execute the request, you would need to subscribe, and return the Uni to Quarkus (so Quarkus will subscribe)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just one more question, is there any way to make the requests by blocks of 100s (for example)? I mean, when I launch thousands of them, the server responds with: "Connection was closed". So I don't know If there is a way to make small blocks to ensure the availability of the system. Thx!

Comment: Yes, you can group items, using `multi.group().asLists().of(100)`